# browserify loading ReactJS twice with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify, react-router

I use browserify to bundle ReactJS and (among others) [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router).
But when I look in the console, the message ...

```
Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: http://fb.me/react-devtools
```

... shows up **twice** (!) telling me that in fact two ReactJS instances are running.

If I look in my browserified JS I saw the ReactJS source only once.

How would I avoid this?

`package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "LiveScript": "^1.3.0",
    "jquery": "*",
    "firebase": "*",
    "react": "0.11.2",
    "reactfire": "*",
    "react-router": "*",
    ...
}
```

When I run `npm ls | grep -i react` I get:

```
___ react@0.11.2
___ react-router@0.9.4
___ reactfire@0.3.0
_ ___ react@0.11.2
```

Comment: Is it possible you have an old reference to the CDN-hosted React source in your HTML somewhere?

Comment: CDN-hosted React? I'm using **npm** to fetch it. That shouldn't be an issue, right?

Comment: are you npm linking to any libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Run `npm dedupe`.  Most likely it's just two different patch versions of react.

You should never use wildcards for dependencies.  For reactfire `<0.1`, and react-router `^0.9`.

Comment: UPDATED my question with ```npm ls```

I'll try dedupe now.

Comment: Didn't work! I tried looking at it with ```npm ls``` where *react* in fact showed up twice, then ```npm dedupe```d it which removed the duplicate *react*.
But after building with *browserify* it still shows the ```Download the DevTools ...``` twice in the console.

Comment: Still, good advice with ```npm dedupe```. Maybe I'll add ```npm shrinkwrap``` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are importing react with a different name. for example

```
var React = require('react');
```

and

```
var React = require('React');
```

will cause react to be imported react twice.